# Optimizing use of variables for values that are only used once

Tags: java, variables, optimization

I come across this doubt a lot and I could use some opinions about it.
I frequently use variables for values that are only used once and I'm not sure if there's a right or wrong way to do it. Is there any convention guideline about this?

A simple example:

```
int matches = 10;
int victories = 4;
int defeats = 3;

int ties = (matches - (victories + defeats));
int score = (victories*3 + ties);
```

Should `ties` be removed so that it becomes this?

```
int matches = 10;
int victories = 4;
int defeats = 3;

int score = (victories*3 + (matches - (victories + defeats)));
```

Despite the silly example, I've wondered about this on situations of different complexities.

I can see some Pros and Cons of using `ties`:

Pros:

- Improves Readability
- `ties` can be used later if needed
- Easier maintenance

Cons:

- Less compact code
- Makes use of more variables
- Uses resources unnecessarily

Maybe this is just a situation of personal taste but let me know how you deal with this and why. Thanks!

Comment: It seems a non-issue to me. Use whatever you understand the best, now, and 6 months from now.

Comment: Should "ties" bermoved and stuff? Short answer: Yes, if you want to. But @HovercraftFullOfEels is right, this only matters if you use a lot of such code repeatedly, over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise the first version.Since most of the time we work as teams and it would be best if the code is better readable and less cumbersome.The memory optimization which the second version is aiming at would not help much(infact nothing), as JVM already does a very good memory deallocation for us.
If it is a local variable: JVM deallocates all variables(local variables) in a LIFO fashion(w.r.t call stack) 
If it is a member variable: JVM would garbage collect all objects(which consists of the member variables as well) stored in the heap on a regular basis.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you use whichever version is easiest to read. Between the compiler and JIT you performing micro-optimization like that is not going to yield any measurable performance difference in real world applications.

Comment: Exactly, 1+. [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1103299/2970947).